# rgdal package is not working in R 4.2.3 used Sf package but without success

Tags: r, rgdal

rgdal packge is not working anymore. I used writeOGR

```
 writeOGR(occ_sp, species_set[i], driver = "ESRI Shapefile", dsn = dsn, overwrite = TRUE)
```

error:

> Error in writeOGR(occ_sp, species_set[i], driver = "ESRI Shapefile", dsn = dsn,  :
> could not find function "writeOGR"

I moved to use  st_write to save my spatialpointsdataframe to shape file. This produce the errors.

```
st_write(occ_sp,"occ_sp.shp")
```

error:

> Error in UseMethod("st_write") :
> no applicable method for 'st_write' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPointsDataFrame', 'SpatialPoints', 'Spatial', 'SpatialVector')"